# Atualizando uma subcollection no Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Tenho uma collection chamada `purchase` com vários dados, dentre eles:

```
const purchase = new Schema({
    datePurchase:{type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    ...
    products:[{
        product: {type: String},
        category: {type: String},
        price: {type: Number},
        additional:{ type: Array}, //Dados do adicional
        observation:{ type: String},
    }],
    ...
}
```

Fiz um controller para atualizar a subcollection `products`, ainda farei o de excluir:

```
async updateProduct(req,res){
        await purchaseModel.update({
            id: req.params._id, 
            idProduct: req.params.products._id
        }, 
        req.body,
        {new: true})
        .then(response =>{
            return res.status(200).json(response)
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            return res.status(500).json(error)
        })
    }
```

Porém, quando simulo a atualização, recebo o seguinte erro:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Esse `_id` se refere claramante ao `id` de `products`.

Não encontrei uma solução adequada. Gostaria de uma ajuda a formular uma atualização e uma exclusão que funcionem.

Comment: Uma duvida, esta correto essa declaracao do `new Schema`? O objeto nao deveria estar dentro do `new Schema({...})`?

Comment: Está como ```Schema({...})```, eu que errei na digitação. Alterei o post.